# javascript + jquery ajax : conditional "data" element

Tags: javascript, function, jquery

I would like to create a function around an ajax call so that I can re-use it. But I'm having trouble populating the `data: ({ … })` part of it based on conditions (via a `switch`).

```
var d = {};
function lookup (what,etat,compt,vile,zip) {
    switch(what) {
        case "cou_mun":
            d: ({
                lookup: "county",
                state: etat
            })
            break;
        case "city":
            d: ({
                lookup: "city",
                state: etat,
                county: compt
            })
            break;
        case "zipcode":
            d: ({
                lookup: "zipcode",
                state: etat,
                county: compt,
                city: vile
            })
            break;
        default:break;
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: "socioGeo_envnLookup.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: d,
            //lookup: "county", //"county" or "city" or "zipcode"
            //state: etat
            //county: cou_mun,
            //city: city,
        success: function(what,data) {
            $('select[name="'+what+'"]').html(data);
        }
    }); //$.ajax
} //lookup()
```

And then I would call it like `lookup("city",state,county);`

IE complains when I try to make an ajax call that sends undefined variables, so I want to set `data: ({ … })` dynamically.

Comment: You have to **assign** a value to `d` which is done by the assignment operator `=`. Also make sure that you define `d` locally in your function.

Comment: @FelixKling Do you know why `what` in `success:` as the value that should be in `data`? I did `alert('what = '+what+'\n'+'data = '+data.toSource);` inside of success and `what` = the html that should be in `data` and `data = function toSource() { [native code] }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
d: ({
            lookup: "county",
            state: etat
        })
```

Should be

```
d = {
        lookup: "county",
        state: etat
    };
```

Comment: ah, that does help. Do you know why `what` in `success:` as the value that should be in `data`? I did `alert('what = '+what+'\n'+'data = '+data.toSource);` inside of success and `what` = the html that should be in `data` and `data = function toSource() { [native code] }`

Comment: success has the following signature:  `success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)`.  The first parameter is the data, the 2nd is the status.  That is why `what` is the data.  It doesn't matter what you name that parameter, jquery will pass the data as the first parameter.

Comment: Ah. Okay. How do I pass `what` to `success` so I can load the data into a specified select?

Comment: You don't have to pass it, just use it.  It will be accessible inside of the success function.

Comment: Ohh, that's unexpected. Thanks! I'll try when I have server-access on Monday :)